# Inspect Google Cloud Task Queue retry parameters from Task

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I have created a Cloud Task that has a retry policy with max attempts set to (for example 4).

However, we want the Task to fallback to a default solution if the Task fails for the last time.

That is, if the Task fails on the first time we just log the error and return `500`. And again for the second time. And the third. Etc... but if the current `TaskRetryCount` is the last attempt for that queue (i.e. 4 in this example) then we will execute some fallback behaviour before returning `500` for the last time.

I can see from the [Cloud Tasks HTTP Handler docs](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#handler) that I can get the `X-CloudTasks-TaskRetryCount` from the header of the request. But it doesn't seem to have a way to get the `max-attempts` for the queue.

Is that something that I can get hold of?

Or am I approaching this wrongly? Is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Why do you use Cloud Task, and not PubSub for example? Do you need some specific feature of Cloud Task?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute something on the last retry you can use the below code.

It uses [@google-cloud/tasks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/tasks) to get `maxAttempts` from the queue and then compares that to the `taskRetryCount` found in the [task header](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks).

```TypeScript
import { CloudTasksClient } from '@google-cloud/tasks';

// Get the task queue
const tasksClient = new CloudTasksClient();
const request = {
  name: `projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/${LOCATION}/queues/${TASK_QUEUE_NAME}`,
};
const taskQueue = await tasksClient.getQueue(request);

// Get maxAttempts
const maxAttempts = Number(taskQueue[0].retryConfig?.maxAttempts);

// Get taskRetryCount
const taskRetryCount = Number(req.headers['x-cloudtasks-taskretrycount']);

  // We need to use "taskRetryCount + 1" to trigger something on the last retry
  // We need to check for "maxAttempts != -1" because -1 is unlimited attempts
if (maxAttempts != -1 && taskRetryCount + 1 == maxAttempts) {
  // Do something here on the last retry
}
```

**Note 1**: I had to use lowercase headers for mine to work. I.e. `x-cloudtasks-taskretrycount` instead of `X-CloudTasks-TaskRetryCount` as found in the Google Docs.

**Note 2**: In the answer by @Avishay28 it is suggested to use `x-cloudtasks-taskexecutioncount` instead of `x-cloudtasks-taskretrycount`, but I believe that if your trying to do something in the last retry you should be using `x-cloudtasks-taskretrycount`.

Here is the description taken [from the docs](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#handler):

- **X-CloudTasks-TaskRetryCount**: The number of times this task has been retried. For the first attempt, this value is 0. This number includes attempts where the task failed due to 5XX error codes and never reached the execution phase.
- **X-CloudTasks-TaskExecutionCount**: The total number of times that the task has received a response from the handler. Since Cloud Tasks deletes the task once a successful response has been received, all previous handler responses were failures. This number does not include failures due to 5XX error codes.

So if your task returns a `5xx` code or something happened and the task never got executed, then `taskretrycount` will be higher then `taskexecutioncount`. And since the task will end when `taskretrycount` is more than `maxAttempts` there may be a situtation where the task will end before you can do something in the last task.

The other option is to use `taskexecutioncount` and never return a `5xx` status error from your task, but I think that is likely to produce unexpected results in the future when you eventually forget that rule. Also it doesn't account for times when something else happened and the task never got executed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the tasks are created with Cloud Tasks the queue-level retry settings apply to all tasks in the queue that were created using Cloud Tasks (as they cannot be set on individual tasks). Calling the [projects.locations.queues.get method](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues/get) from the REST API should return the [RetryConfig](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues#retryconfig) settings from the Queue that include the `maxAttempts` field that you require.

For tasks created with the App Engine SDK you should refer to this [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/retrying-tasks) (although I believe that approach is deprecated and not useful for your use case).

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the queue max attempts value using [getQueue](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues/get) call and inspecting queue.retryConfig.maxAttempts, and use the [header `X-CloudTasks-TaskRetryCount`](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#handler) to check the current retry, if maxAttempt != -1 && maxAttempt == (retry+1) your in the last retry.

Note that `X-CloudTasks-TaskRetryCount` counting only tasks that return 5xx status code, and also tasks that did not get to the execution phase (to your code).
If you want to count only failed attempts happend in your exeuction phase, you should use the header `X-CloudTasks-TaskExecutionCount`
and make sure your code return 4xx status code in case of an error.
As per the docs:

> **X-CloudTasks-TaskExecutionCount** The total number of times that the task has received a response from the handler. Since Cloud Tasks
> deletes the task once a successful response has been received, all
> previous handler responses were failures. This number does not include
> failures due to 5XX error codes.

Comment: Note that the `X-CloudTasks-TaskExecutionCount` is the one you should use instead. The one you mentioned will not count as a retry for max retries since it includes those that did not get to the execution phase https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#handler

Comment: This one would not work if my handler return status 500 to indicate a fail task.
What about tasks that DID get to the execution phase, and return status 500?

Comment: Hrmm yea good point, you are right. I've come from using tasks in AppEngine for years and cloud tasks were _meant_ to be the same, but it appears this is where they differ. Thanks for pointing this out. https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers#reading_app_engine_task_request_headers

Comment: Yep in app engine this is different.. This is still an issue because if you use `X-CloudTasks-TaskRetryCount` like I suggested you may count retries that you don't want to count (i.e any error occurred before your code event start running)
I guess google expect you to use 4xx status code for any error from your handler